# Can you change the height of an ExpansionTile in Flutter?

Tags: widget, accordion, flutter

The [ExpansionTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) inherits from the [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html), which has a fixed height. There are no input args for tile height.

I've tried wrapping the ExpansionTile in a Container widget with a hardcoded height, but that causes the children widgets to only take up the space within the hardcoded height. Currently, because the contents in the `title` widget are large, I have a "Column overflowed by 23 pixels" message.

Is there any way to change an Expansion Tile's height? Or is there another Widget I could use that has the expansion/accordion feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably copy `ExpansionTile` and make your own version. Sizing `ListTile` is easy with a `Container` or `SizedBox`, but `ExpansionTile` is a material widget and it doesn't look like it was built with your use case in mind.

Comment: How do you size a ListTile?

Answer (score 6):

Came across this in 2023, it turns out the `ListTile` can be 'controlled' by a theme.

```dart
  /// Whether this list tile is part of a vertically dense list.
  ///
  /// If this property is null then its value is based on [ListTileTheme.dense].
  ///
  /// Dense list tiles default to a smaller height.
  ///
  /// It is not recommended to set [dense] to true when [ThemeData.useMaterial3] is true.
  final bool? dense;
```

Deep in the library you can find this code:

```dart
  double get _defaultTileHeight {
    final bool hasSubtitle = subtitle != null;
    final bool isTwoLine = !isThreeLine && hasSubtitle;
    final bool isOneLine = !isThreeLine && !hasSubtitle;

    final Offset baseDensity = visualDensity.baseSizeAdjustment;
    if (isOneLine) {
      return (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + baseDensity.dy;
    }
    if (isTwoLine) {
      return (isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0) + baseDensity.dy;
    }
    return (isDense ? 76.0 : 88.0) + baseDensity.dy;
  }
```

So simply wrap the `ExpansionTile` in a `Theme` and set `dense: true`

```dart
Theme(
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            listTileTheme: ListTileTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            dense: true,
          ),
        ),
   child: ExpansionTile(...),
),
```

While not a full control, the height of `48` was exactly the value I was looking for.

Comment: Besides doing that, I also set

visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        listTileTheme: ListTileTheme.of(context)
            .copyWith(dense: true, minVerticalPadding: 16),
      ),
      child: ExpansionTile(
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this package : [configurable_expansion_tile](https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile)

[image]

Example app :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:configurable_expansion_tile/configurable_expansion_tile.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Configurable Expansion Tile Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Configurable Expansion Tile Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ConfigurableExpansionTile(
              borderColorStart: Colors.blue,
              borderColorEnd: Colors.orange,
              animatedWidgetFollowingHeader: const Icon(
                Icons.expand_more,
                color: const Color(0xFF707070),
              ),
              headerExpanded:
                  Flexible(child: Center(child: Text("A Header Changed"))),
              header: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Center(child: Text("A Header"))),
              headerBackgroundColorStart: Colors.grey,
              expandedBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              headerBackgroundColorEnd: Colors.teal,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[Text("CHILD 1")],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[Text("CHILD 2")],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should get you the results you wanted.

Hope it helps,

Thanks

Comment: Suggested package hasn't been updated in 3 years and is not compatible with null safty.
Use this one: https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile_null_safety

Comment: ```Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:configurable_expansion_tile```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tilePadding Property

```
 ExpansionTile(
                title: Text("some Text"),
                tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              ),
```

Comment: Same issues as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63264455/4405821

Answer (score -1):

wrap the 'ExpansionTile' inside a 'Container' and set the margin

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: .5.sw),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColor.profileBoarderColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: AppColor.profileBoarderColor)
                  ),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title: AppTextView(text: 'Seeson 01',),
                    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: 200,
                          child: ListTile(title: AppTextView(text: 'Seeson 01',),));
                    }
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score -2):

**This is a workaround:** you can use **title** of the ExpansionTile widget to render the entire content instead of using leading or trailing. You can add padding to title widget to increase height of the ExpansionTile.

Comment: This works for making the title larger, but not for reducing its size :-).